# ClosedXML: Detection of Formula in Excel Cell

Tags: c#, vb.net, random, formula, closedxml

I noticed that if an Excel cell contains a formula to generate a random uniform variate, i.e., =rand(), that ClosedXML will only read a 0 or 1 based on rounding off to the nearest integer.  Question is, can the actual formula result be read in, or can the use of a formula be detected to tell the user e.g. "Use of formulas in an input Excel files is not recommended."

Comment: Have you tried `Cell(x,y).GetValue<double>()` to read the cell value not as an integer?

Comment: There can be text in the Excels, so would enforcing double cause a problem reading text?

Comment: Probably. use `GetValue<string>()` then and `double.TryParse()` afterwards to check if it is a double value.

Comment: I already use `double.TryParse()` after reading an Excel, so there's no sense in using it twice.   Why isn't there something like `.GetValue<object>`, which would read integers, doubles, and strings?